# Image loads after complete page load in another any section

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly, my main aim is to load an image after page load. Next, I don't want to specify the image tag in my HTML code so I don't need to provide any src attribute.

Suppose this is my tag which should load image after page load

```
<head>
    <p title="image_source" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></p>
</head>

var imagetag = document.createElement('img');
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    for (var x=0; x < document.getElementsByTagName('p').length; x++) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question than ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use jQuery (if possible) for more complex tasks, like this one.

Comment: please dont give any answer for few min

Comment: imagetag.setAttribute(imagesource);

Comment: this works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use data attributes and a class to add images to the page after it is loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img_load")
  imgs.forEach(function (el) {
     var img = document.createElement("img");
     img.src = el.dataset.src
     el.appendChild(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="img_load" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></p>
<p class="img_load" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></p>
<p class="img_load" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x450" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></p>
```

Comment: i tried your code with #p tag but i cant make it because images were overlapping even after i positioned them relative...i don't know why it happened but i used #a tag instead of #p and this code works ....i also made a little change on your code to make it more easy for me :-)   THANK YOU

Comment: i got it ...when u create a new img tag inside the p tag the size of p tag does not affect image size so i need to resize the img  tag rather than resizing the p tag . just a bit of code

Answer (score 0):

this script loads all image after the entire page completes its loading

each #a tag with class img_load will load image by taking data-scr as source of image

### javascript

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('img_load');
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++){
parent[i].appendChild(document.createElement('img')).setAttribute('src',
parent[i].getAttribute('data-src'));}})
</script>
```

### html

```
<a class="img_load" data-src="image_source.png" 
style="height:00px;width:100px;position:relative;"></a>
<a class="img_load" data-src="image_source.jpg" 
style="height:100px;width:100px;position:relative;">b</a>
```

Comment: Is this any different that the answer that was already posted? (Except that you have changed the OP's `p` tag to `a` tag and added css for some reason.)

Comment: a little different ... #p tag were overlapping ...if u could find why that happen plz fix your code . i tried style position relative but that didn't work